# PySide popup showing list and multiple select

Tags: python, pyside

I am programming a GUI using PySide. I currently have the user select a directory with many data files in it. I load these filenames into a list. I would like the GUI to display a popup menu showing the list of filenames allowing the user to select one, many or all the files to proceed. Right now I am using,

```
items, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(self, "Select files", "List of files", datafiles, 0, False)
```

This only lets the user select one file, and not multiple. How can I show the user a list of items and have them highlight as many as they want and then return the list?

Thanks!

Comment: The QInputDialog class provides a simple convenience dialog to get a **single** value from the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QInputDialog class provides a simple convenience dialog to get a **single** value from the user, but we can create custom dialog.

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QFormLayout, \
    QLabel, QListView, QPushButton, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel, QWidget


class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,  title, message, items, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        form = QFormLayout(self)
        form.addRow(QLabel(message))
        self.listView = QListView(self)
        form.addRow(self.listView)
        model = QStandardItemModel(self.listView)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        for item in items:
            # create an item with a caption
            standardItem = QStandardItem(item)
            standardItem.setCheckable(True)
            model.appendRow(standardItem)
        self.listView.setModel(model)

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, Qt.Horizontal, self)
        form.addRow(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def itemsSelected(self):
        selected = []
        model = self.listView.model()
        i = 0
        while model.item(i):
            if model.item(i).checkState():
                selected.append(model.item(i).text())
            i += 1
        return selected


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Select', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')

    def showDialog(self):
        items = [str(x) for x in range(10)]
        dial = MyDialog("Select files", "List of files", items, self)
        if dial.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
            print(dial.itemsSelected())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

After clicked button:

[image]

Output:

```
['1', '2', '4', '5']
```

Comment: Great! This is just what I was looking for, thanks so much :)